# Problem with wrapfig2

Tags: wrapfigure, wrapfig2

I don't understand how the wrapfig2 package works.
I tried it with a Tikz figure and the figure wasn't wrapped.
So I tried with the example of the document package (page 4) and it doesn't work either.
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig2}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{50mm}
  \centering\unitlength=1mm
  \begin{picture}(40,30)
        \polygon(0,0)(40,0)(40,30)(0,30)
        \Line(0,0)(40,30)
    \end{picture}
    \caption{Un essai}
\end{wrapfigure}
{texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte
texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte texte }
\end{document}
```

And here is the result:
[image]

So I guess, I am doing something wrong but what?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just remove the curly brackets from your text.

Comment: What a stupid mistake I had made. Thank you @miltos

Comment: There is no stupid mistakes,  just only mistakes and anyone can make! You are welcome!